# Issue with webelement.send_keys() in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have an issue with `webelement.send_keys()` in python using both `firefox` and `chrome`.

Using `Selenium`:

```
driver.get('http://www.youtube.com')
searchbar = driver.find_element_by_id('masthead-search-term')
searchbar.clear()
searchbar.send_keys(songName)
searchbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # <-This line is the problem.
```

So the weird thing is, it works, but then crashes.

I get this error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

any ideas?

Comment: it seems as if youtube begins loading without send_keys(Keys.RETURN) being sent,  so that's the issue. Solved?

Comment: What are you doing right after sending return?